# How to pass parameter to asynchronous task in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

During an ASP.NET web request I need to kick off an asynchronous task and then return control back to the web page.  Can someone show me the code for calling the below method?  Just to be clear, I want the function called async and the web request to complete returning control to the calling page while the function is still processing.

```
private void FunctionToCall(IInterface objectIWantToPassIn)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Comment: Sorry, 4.5. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: "Async" as in the `async` keyword, or "async" as in new thread?

Comment: async as in a new thread, but if the solution uses the new async keyboard, that would be fine.  My needs are simple.  I just want to kick off a new thread.  I don't care if it throws an exception (presumably it will just die), I don't care when it ends (but I know it will never take more than a few seconds), and I don't need to resync with the caller.  I want the calling web request to continue and finish while FunctionToCall runs on another thread.

Comment: There are so many ways to do this! This will also work: `((Action<IInterface>)FunctionToCall).BeginInvoke(objectIWantToPassIn, null, null);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to spawn the thread by creating a

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action, "arg");
```

then you'll want to do something maybe when the task is done:

```
task.ContinueWith(anotheraction);
```

Of course action and otheraction would be void methods in this case.

Comment: Both answers are correct and appreciated.  However, this one uses the new TPL which is now preferred by the MS CLR team. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/06/9903475.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void FunctionToCall(object state)
 {
        IInterface objectIWantToPassIn= (IInterface ) state;
        // do stuff
 }

  System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FunctionToCall, 
                                                objectIWantToPassIn);
```